# I want fetch custom post with taxonomy id

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I want to fetch custom post by  custom taxonomy id , Here is my custom code.

```
function services_custom_init() {
 $labels = array(
   'name' => _x('services', 'post type general name'),
   'singular_name' => _x('services', 'post type singular name'),
   'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'services'),
   'add_new_item' => __('Add New services'),
   'edit_item' => __('Edit services'),
   'new_item' => __('New services'),
   'all_items' => __('All services'),
   'view_item' => __('View services'),
   'search_items' => __('Search services'),
   'not_found' =>  __('No services found'),
   'not_found_in_trash' => __('No services found in Trash'), 
   'parent_item_colon' => '',
   'menu_name' => __('Services')

 );
 $args = array(
   'labels' => $labels,
   'public' => true,

   'publicly_queryable' => true,
   'show_ui' => true, 
   'show_in_menu' => true, 
   'query_var' => true,
   'rewrite' => true,
   'capability_type' => 'post',
   'has_archive' => true, 
   'hierarchical' => false,
   'menu_position' => null,
   'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
 ); 



 register_post_type('services',$args);
}
add_action( 'init', 'services_custom_init' );


//hook into the init action and call create_book_taxonomies when it fires
add_action( 'init', 'create_myservices_hierarchical_taxonomy', 0 );
function create_myservices_hierarchical_taxonomy() {


  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'myservices', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'myservices', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search myservices' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All myservices' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent myservices' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent myservices:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit myservices' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update myservices' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New myservices' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New myservices Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Myservices' ),
  );    

// Now register the taxonomy

  register_taxonomy('myservices',array('services'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'services' ),
  ));

}
```

And here is code for fetch custom post by taxonomy id

```
<?php $custom_terms = get_terms('myservices');

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'services',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'myservices',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
            ),
        ),
     );

     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
        echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';

        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';

       <?php  endwhile; ?>
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: What's the problem that you're experiencing? Your code works for me; Each `myservices` taxonomy term is listed then a link to each post which is associated with that term is listed underneath. The only issue is the extra PHP tags around the `endwhile` statement.

Comment: code is working for me also!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you Need To change Your tax_query:

'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'myservices',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $custom_term->ID,
            ),
        ),